# Values not aligned when using tabulary

Tags: tables, tabulary

I have a problem with properly displaying following table:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float,lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeatletter
\def\hlinewd#1{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height #1 \futurelet
   \reserved@a\@xhline}
\makeatother
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Yearly membership growth for different time periods}
  \scriptsize
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL}
    \hlinewd{1.25pt}
    \textbf{a. Time period 1886 - 1892:} & \textbf{} & \textbf{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{1-8}    \multicolumn{1}{C}{86} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{87} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{88} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{89} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{90} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{91} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{92} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{AVG} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{1-8}    \multicolumn{1}{C}{485} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{229} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{372} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{401} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{488} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{261} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{444} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{383} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{1-8}          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut[t]\\
    \textbf{b. Time period 1911 - 1926:} & \textbf{} & \textbf{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{C}{11} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{12} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{13} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{14} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{15} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{16} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{17} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{18} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{19} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{20} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{21} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{22} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{23} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{24} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{25} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{26} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{AVG} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{C}{338} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{929} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{528} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{1'426} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{-301} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{117} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{375} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{293} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{652} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{2'671} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{1'370} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{544} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{786} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{479} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{440} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{800} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{715} \bigstrut\\
    \hlinewd{1.25pt}
    \end{tabulary}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

The result looks like in the following picture:

[image: Table]

While the positioning of the table is fine, I don't understand why latex, after starting with the first set of numbers, puts the rest all to the right. The numbers on the right (87, 88, 89, ....) should be aligned to the left too. How can I manage this for this table?

Many thanks for your help, as always!

Comment: the posted code generates multiple errors (not least missing `\begin{document}` but still generates errors if that is added. Please post code that generates the image shown

Comment: the numbers 87,... are left aligned in their column, so I don't understand your comment that they are "to the right" ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `tabular` and `\multicolumn{17}{l}{...}` for the entries spanning columns:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Yearly membership growth for different time periods}
\label{tab:addlabel}

\scriptsize

\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-1.8pt}
\begin{tabular}{*{17}{c}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{17}{l}{\textbf{a. Time period 1886--1892}} \\

\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth]{1-8}

86 & 87 & 88 & 89 & 90 & 91 & 92 & AVG & & & & & & & & & \\

\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth]{1-8}

485 & 229 & 372 & 401 & 488 & 261 & 444 & 383 & & & & & & & & & \\

\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth]{1-8}

\multicolumn{17}{l}{\textbf{b. Time period 1911--1926}} \\

\midrule

11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & AVG \\

\midrule

338 & 929 & 528 & 1426 & $-301$ & 117 & 375 & 293 & 652 & 2671 & 1370 & 544 & 786 &
  479 & 440 & 800 & 715 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Yearly membership growth for different time periods}
\label{tab:addlabel-double}

\footnotesize

\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-3.1pt}
\begin{tabular}{*{17}{c}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{17}{l}{\textbf{a. Time period 1886--1892}} \\

\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth]{1-8}

86 & 87 & 88 & 89 & 90 & 91 & 92 & AVG & & & & & & & & & \\

\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth]{1-8}

485 & 229 & 372 & 401 & 488 & 261 & 444 & 383 & & & & & & & & & \\

\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth]{1-8}

\multicolumn{17}{l}{\textbf{b. Time period 1911--1926}} \\

\midrule

11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & AVG \\

\midrule

338 & 929 & 528 & 1426 & $-301$ & 117 & 375 & 293 & 652 & 2671 & 1370 & 544 & 786 &
  479 & 440 & 800 & 715 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

No need for `\bigstrut` or complicated code for heavier rules.

I provided two versions of the table, the second uses `\footnotesize`.

How did I compute the `-3.1pt` fix?

I ran the document without `\addtolength` and got, for the second case, an overfull by 104.69522pt. Since 104.69522/34 is approximately 3.079, I rounded up.

Similarly for the first version.

[image]

If you want some vertical space above the second heading, use `\addlinespace`

```
...

485 & 229 & 372 & 401 & 488 & 261 & 444 & 383 & & & & & & & & & \\

\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth]{1-8}

\addlinespace[\medskipamount]

\multicolumn{17}{l}{\textbf{b. Time period 1911--1926}} \\

\midrule

...
```

[image]

Comment: Astounding help, really appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: @MadJens Some manual work is needed if you want a good product. Add those fixes (`\addtolength`) only when the document is in its final form: changing the line width might make the fix obsolete. When I work on a document, I ignore the overfull box messages and examine them at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! One last thing: is it also possible to make the first and last hline bolder/wider so that they stand out a little more?

Comment: @MadJens `\toprule[20pt]` would be much thicker. The same for `\bottomrule`. But the default thickness is already quite good.

Answer (score 3):

the later columns are all left aligned, but the first column is very wide due to

```
 \textbf{a. Time period 1886 - 1892:}
```

which forces the width of the column. perhaps you intended to use `\multicolumn` so that spanned all the columns rather than forcing the first column to be wide?

`tabulary` (and `tabularx`) are unsuited to this kind of table, they work by changing the *line breaking* width specified in each column. Since your columns mainly consist of numerical data line breaking is not relevant and you would be better to use a standard `tabular`.